# Simple List from a text file with Java

Tags: java

I'm currently studying and also I'm new with Java programming, I have a question about nodes and simple lists.

I have to read two files that looks like this `L1: 1, 5, 8, 4` and `L2: 4, 8, 9, 4` and store them in a `List` not an `Array`. I wrote some code but it's not what I was supposed to do, so if you could help me to understand Nodes and Lists I'd really appreciate it.

Also after reading the files, another list has to be generated with the sum of the other two lists. This sum has to be with the positions of the list so it should look like this `L3: 5, 13, 17, 8`

This is the code I used:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Read {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileReader fr, fr2;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(new File("list1.txt"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = br.readLine();

            fr2 = new FileReader(new File("list2.txt"));
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fr2);
            String line2 = br2.readLine();

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ", ");
            int dimension = st.countTokens();
            int sum = 0;
            int sum2 = 0;
            int total = 0;

            int[] arrNum = new int[dimension];

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                System.out.print("List 1: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
                    arrNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    System.out.print(arrNum[i] + ", ");
                    sum += arrNum[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\nThe sum of the first list is: " + sum + "\n");

            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line2, ", ");
            int dimension2 = st2.countTokens();

            int[] arrNum2 = new int[dimension2];

            while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                System.out.print("List 2: ");
                for (int j = 0; j < arrNum2.length; j++) {
                    arrNum2[j] = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
                    System.out.print(arrNum2[j] + ", ");
                    sum2 += arrNum2[j];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\nThe sum of the second list is: " + sum2);

            total = sum + sum2;
            System.out.println("\nThe sum of the lists are: " + total);

            br.close();
            br2.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can tell me how to do this with the List and Nodes.

Comment: What do you mean by `"but it's not what I was suppoused to do..."`? Can you provide more detail? Also, can you format your code better? Is your code always fully left-justified or do you use indentation to help others and yourself better understand your code?

Comment: Maybe you have to use `List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); l1.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));`. I'm assuming this since you don't specify if you have to use List interface or make a LinkedList implementation.

Answer (score 0):

See the `LinkedList` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and [examples](http://www.roseindia.net/java/jdk6/linkedlistexample.shtml)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the thing is that I have to use LinkedLists and for what I've been looking this use Nodes so it can be linked to the next one.

As for the code I had it formated in a different way, but since this is the first time I post a code I had a bit of troubles posting it, and this was the only way I could post it.